# How to add multiple services in grpc-js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, grpc, grpc-node

Lets say I have .proto file like below:

```
service SvcOne{
    rpc MehtodOne(RequestOne) returns (ResponseOne) {}
}

service SvcTwo{
    rpc MethodTwo(RequestTwo) returns (ResponseTwo) {}
}

message RequestOne {
    string field_req= 1;
}

message ResponseOne {
    string field_res = 1;
}

message RequestTwo {
    string field_req= 1;
}

message ResponseTwo {
    string field_res = 1;
}
```

and then I try the code like below :

```
const server = new grpc.Server();      
server.addService(protoSchema.SvcOne.service, {MehtodOne: MethodOne});
server.addService(protoSchema.SvcTwo.service, {MethodTwo: MethodTwo});
server.bindAsync(
    "0.0.0.0:50051",
    grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure(),
    (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error!");
      } else {
        routeServer.start();
        console.log("Server ready...");
      }
    }
  );
```

but got an error like this :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'service' of undefined
```

So I think I missing something in between.

**The question:**
How to bind multiple services (SvcOne & SvcTwo) in grpc-js server ? or is that not possible in grpc-js ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'm doing for this kind of scenario is define different services on it's own block in one proto file.

```
package servicePackage;

service Service1 {
    rpc Get(Empty) returns (Empty);
    rpc Insert(Empty) returns (Empty);
    rpc Remove(Empty) returns (Empty);
    rpc Update(Empty) returns (Empty);
}

service Service2 {
    rpc Get(Empty) returns (Empty);
    rpc Insert(Empty) returns (Empty);
    rpc Remove(Empty) returns (Empty);
    rpc Update(Empty) returns (Empty);
}
```

Then on addService just use each service name

```
server.addService(grpcPackage.Service1.service, {
   Insert: async (call, callback) => {
       callback(null, null);
   },
});

server.addService(grpcPackage.Service2.service, {
   Insert: async (call, callback) => {
       callback(null, null);
   },
});
```

The rest like binding, protoLoading, server.start() stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Please reference [route_guide_server](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.38.0/examples/node/dynamic_codegen/route_guide/route_guide_server.js#L221), did you load definition before add start server like [this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.38.0/examples/node/dynamic_codegen/route_guide/route_guide_server.js#L35)?

Comment: Yes I do route guide and load proto definition before add start server like the link you provided. The problem only accour when adding 2nd `server.addService()`, If I only use one `server.addService()` it working fine without any problem.  @HelloWood